# Angular HTTP Post using CORS works behind the scene, but doesn't "succeed"

Tags: asp.net-mvc, http, angularjs, cors

I'm working on an AngularJS project, and I need to perform a **cross-domain (CORS) POST**.
It took me a (long) while to get it working, and well, it now sort of work:

- **The pre flight (OPTIONS) request is sent correctly**, and my server
  responds to it correctly as well.
- **The actual POST request is sent
  correctly as well**, my server receives it all right, and returns a 201
  (created) response as it should.

*So what is the problem?*

Well the Angular $http object doesn't then go to the "success" callback, but to the "error" callback instead... with a status code of 0 and no specific error.
So from my page, I have no way to know if my request actually worked. The only way I know that it does work is by controlling (debugging) the server and using Fiddler.

Did anybody run into this problem before? It's a bit frustrating to have a working solution but not being able to tell that it actually worked :)

**Here is my $http request:**

```
this.simulate = function (url, content) {
var deferred = $q.defer();

var data = { "Data": content, "Timestamp": new Date() };

$http.defaults.useXDomain = true;
$http.post(url, data)
    .then(function(response) {
        deferred.resolve({
            isSuccess: true,
            httpCode: response.status,
            errorMessage: "",
            url: url,
            data:data
        });
    },function(response) { // This is this error callback that is being called, despite the fact that my request is working fine...
        deferred.resolve({
            isSuccess: false,
            httpCode: response.status,
            errorMessage: response.data.Message + " " + response.data.ExceptionMessage,
            url: url,
            data: data
        });
    });

return deferred.promise;
};
```

In fiddler, this is what I get:

**The pre-flight request:**

```
OPTIONS http://myServer:82/xclient/event/volupdate HTTP/1.1
Host: myServer:82
Connection: keep-alive
Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
Origin: http://myClient:1855
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/28.0.1500.95 Safari/537.36
Access-Control-Request-Headers: accept, origin, x-requested-with, authorization, ssotoken, content-type
Accept: */*
DNT: 1
Referer: http://myClient:1855/XClient/testharness/eventing
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6,fr-FR;q=0.4
```

Which gives me that **pre-flight response:**

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: -1
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://myClient:1855
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: accept, origin, x-requested-with, authorization, ssotoken, content-type
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Wed, 07 Aug 2013 10:13:05 GMT
Content-Length: 0
```

And then this is followed by the **actual POST request:**

```
POST http://myServer:82/xclient/event/volupdate HTTP/1.1
Host: myServer:82
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 56
Origin: http://myClient:1855
Authorization: SSOB2L1ax<BLAHBLAHBLAH>EP49w=|0|jaussan|System X|20130825131712|1748001|
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/28.0.1500.95 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
DNT: 1
Referer: http://myClient:1855/XClient/testharness/eventing
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6,fr-FR;q=0.4

{"Data":"SomeData","Timestamp":"2013-08-07T10:13:06.533Z"}
```

And then followed by a normal **201 created response to the POST:**

```
HTTP/1.1 201 Created
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: -1
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Wed, 07 Aug 2013 10:13:05 GMT
Content-Length: 0
```

As you can see everything seems normal, but yet $http seems to think it's not.

Here are a few screenshots from Firebug:

$http goes to the wrong callback:
[image: $http goes to the wrong callback]

And this is the response I'm getting from $http... not really my 201!:
[image: And this is the response I'm getting from $http... not really my 201!]

Comment: It looks like your POST response is missing the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header.

Comment: It was indeed the problem, I had no idea I had to add that header on the POST as well. Thanks for your help!!! Can you add your answer as a proper answer so I can vote on it ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears as if your server is handling the OPTIONS (preflight) request correctly, but not the actual POST request.  Your server needs to at least include an Access-Control-Allow-Origin header in the response to your POST request.  In your case, that would be: `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://myClient:1855`.

For future reference, there is an excellent article about CORS that **everyone** who has to support a cross-origin environment should absolutely bookmark: [MDN on HTTP access control](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS).

Comment: Thanks for the article and your response!